# How to get the length of a Float? (C#)

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# from the 'Fundamentals of Computer Programming with C#' by Svetlin Nakov and others (available for free here: http://www.introprogramming.info/english-intro-csharp-book/)

After each chapter, the authors like to ask questions that go beyond the scope of the chapter. Pg 135, Question 3 asks me to write a program that can correctly compare two real numbers with an accuracy of 0.000001 (7 significant digits).

So I'm using floats to compare the numbers and I decided to add some code that would check to see if the numbers entered are longer than the 7 significant digits that floats can handle. So I need to check for the number of significant digits. Google tells me that I should use sizeof(float) to do that, but I keep getting CS0246 error on the lines of the sizeof check (The type or namespace could not be found.)

The program works if I don't include the code that checks the length of the numbers. I can't find a answer on SO for C#.

What's the problem?

**Edit: Thanks for all the answers. Let me clarify my question: I understand that parsing for string to float automatically checks for validity. However, I tried with my program yesterday, and floats will lose any more than 7 significant digits. So if I compare 0.123457 and 0.12345678, the program will declare that the two numbers are the same because the second number is rounded up. That's why I'm trying to catch for floats longer than 7 digits. I interpret the question this way because it occured to me that these two very similar, but not identical numbers slip through the cracks.**

```
using System;

// Compare two real numbers with up to 0.000001 (7) significant digits
class Compare_Numbers
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Processing the first number
    String firstNumString = null;
    Console.WriteLine("This program compares 2 numbers with upto 7 significant digits.\nEnter the FIRST number with up to 7 significant digits");
    firstNumString = Console.ReadLine();
    float firstNum = Single.Parse(firstNumString);

    if (sizeof(firstNum) > 7)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That number is too long!\nEnter a number with a MAX of 7 significant digits!");
    }

    // Processing the second number
    String secondNumString = null;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the SECOND number with up to 7 significant digits");
    secondNumString = Console.ReadLine();
    float secondNum = Single.Parse(secondNumString);

    if (sizeof(secondNum) > 7)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That number is too long!\nEnter a number with a MAX of 7 significant digits!");
    }

    if (firstNum == secondNum)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The two numbers are the SAME!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The two numbers are DIFFERENT!");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `sizeof` doesn't do what you're thinking. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx

Comment: `sizeof(float)` will give you the number of bytes that a `float` takes to store, not the number of significant digits. You just need to look at the string before parsing and count the digits.

Answer (score 2):

"***How to get the length of a Float?***"

In short, assuming 7 significant digits:

```
  firstNum.ToString("G7").Length // 7 significant digits
```

Ex.

```
  float pi = 3.14159265f;
  string g5 = a.ToString("G5");
  string g7 = a.ToString("G7");
```

However, your title asks something simple, but the body of your question indicates something else. So it appears that you think finding the length of a float is en route to a larger solution. I am not sure, so I will just try to point out several issues.

First, you are misusing **sizeof**; **sizeof**() in C# takes a type, not a variable. (So sizeof(float) would work, but not **sizeof**(num) ).

In any case, **sizeof** it isn't going to give you the number of significant digits. It will give you the number of bytes for the storage of the unmanaged type, which will be constant (4, 8, etc.). Instead, for a given string, use **String.Length**

However, what you *can't* do is try to parse the number to a float, and then try to check for out of range values by checking the float variable. By definition, if you can successfully parse to a float, then it was valid. If it is invalid, it won't parse. The part of your example where you use Single.Parse() and then proceed to try validating using the float variable is moot. You need to validate the string value, or validate that the parse succeeds, or change your approach.

I think the simplest solution is to just use Single.TryParse() and check the boolean return value. if it returns false, either the string value is invalid, or out of range of Single.MinValue and Single.MaxValue. So you might rethink your approach (since it isn't the author's original challenge). I, personally would use the large type in C# for my calculator, but the purpose of the exercise might be to learn these tangential issues, so:

1. If you already have a single precision (float), then you can get the length by converting to a string using Single.ToString() or string.Format() and using **string.Length** on the result, though it will include the decimal point, so account for that.

   See the ToString() and format specifiers at:

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd(v=vs.110).aspx

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx

   The problem with this is by the time you use ToString() you already have a valid float and by that time the check is moot. You need to check the original value. See (2)
2. If you are starting from a string (which in this sample you are reading from console to string, then parsing with Single.Parse(), then you will either get a valid value, or an exception. You need to use a try-catch block with Single.Parse(), otherwise switch to Single.TryParse() and check the boolean return value.

Lastly, if you want to ensure you can both parse the value, as well as validate numbers of greater precision or range, you may add a Double.TryParse() as well.

```
if(!Single.TryParse(str, ref snum)) {
   if(Double.TryParse(str, ref dnum))
       // valid number is out of range for Single
   else
       // valid number is out of range for Double, or invalid
}
```

Or you may use Single.Parse and catch(OverflowException)

```
try {
    snum = Single.Parse(str);
}
catch(OverflowException e) {
}
```

All that was said regarding your actual question, but the spirit of the problem is how to compare 2 valid numbers, in my opinion. In that case, use TryParse() to valid them, then just compare them directly, or use approaches given in @drf's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24482343/257090

Comment: I'm not sure if the solution would be that simple. Wouldn't that throw things off with large numbers?

Comment: @AndrewBarber - As I read the question, he wants to check for significant digits > 7, but not necessarily use that to compare, so I assumed the string version would be adequate for checking. Not necessarily comparing, though. I tweaked my wording. Let me know if you still think I missed something. I may not have thought it through completely.

Comment: I think the 'significant digits' thing is being improperly emphasized here. What he wants is accuracy within +/-0.0000001.

Comment: I agree after re-reading the question and ignoring his code. His code is what led me to believe he wanted the other check.

Comment: Yeah; it threw me at first, too! heh

Comment: Wouldn't it be adequate to check Single.TryParse() for valid return value ?

Comment: +/-0.0000001 precision is not possible with a `float` under any circumstances. For example, `1234.56789` cannot be expressed as such in a float variable without introducing an error (it will become `1234.56787`) It simple is a false assumption that floats have such a +/-0.0000001 precision...

Comment: That is 8 significant digits, though. Right?

Comment: @mrjoltcola, the number i provided is just an example to illustrate the wrong assumption of +/-0.0000001 precision. It just so happened that the number i picked can be stored in a float with 8 digits correctly. However, that is not guaranteed for all numbers; for example try to store -9.87654321 into a float...

Comment: mrjoltcola, thanks for answering. I understand that parsing for string to float automatically checks for validity. 

However, I tried with my program yesterday, and floats will lose any more than 7 significant digits. So if I compare 0.123457 and 0.12345678, the program will declare that the two numbers are the same because the second number is rounded up. 

That's why I'm trying to catch for floats longer than 7 digits. I interpret the question this way because it occured to me that these two very similar, but not identical numbers slip through the cracks. 

Does your solution address this?

Answer (score 2):

```
  static private int GetNumDigitsInFloat(float n)
  {
     string s = n.ToString();
     return s.Length - 1;
  }
```

Comment: Very nice and simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to ensure that two floating-point numbers are approximately equal within 1E-7, there is no need to convert to a string at all.  In fact, using string conversions is probably not a robust approach:

- The question as written requires seven significant figures *after the decimal point*, not seven significant figures total.  The length of the string will include both.
- `Single.ToString` by default only prints 7 digits of precision, but stores up to 9 internally.  The floats 20.000001 and 20.000003 will both convert to "20" by default, but are not equal within 1e-7.  (This is a function of the string conversion, not precision limits with this datatype.)
- Floats can be parsed and output in exponential notation.  What happens if a user enters `1e+20` at the prompt, a perfectly-valid float with a length of 5?

Given two numbers `f1` and `f2`, and an accepted error `ε` of 10^-7, it follows mathematically that `f1` and `f2` should be considered equal (within accepted tolerance) if and only if:

```
 |f1 - f2| ≤ ε
```

Or in C#, we can write the equivalent function:

```
// preconditions: e is non-negativeps, f1 and f2 are not NaN, Inf, or -Inf.
bool AreApproximatelyEqual(float f1, float f2, float eps)
{
    return Math.Abs(f1 - f2) <= eps;
}
```

Given floats `firstNum` and `secondNum`, approximate equality is obtained as:

```
bool equal = AreApproximatelyEqual(firstNum, secondNum, 1e-7f);
```